# Progress Bar value getting reset

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have a Winform with a progress bar, which is being updated from a `CopyFileEx` call.

My callback function (which I think is the problem) is

```
CopyFileCallbackAction myCallback(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, object state, long totalFileSize, long totalBytesTransferred)
{
    double dProgress = ((double)totalBytesTransferred / byteCount) * 100.0;
    backupWorker.ReportProgress((int)dProgress);
    return CopyFileCallbackAction.Continue;
}
```

and the function I call to use `CopyFileEx` is (I don't think the `CopyFileEx` wrapper is relevant to the problem so I haven't posted it)

```
FileRoutines.CopyFile(new FileInfo(source), new FileInfo(dest), CopyFileOptions.All, myCallback);
```

`byteCount` is a `long` combined total size of all the files to be copied.

If I copy only 1 file it works perfectly, but the problems start when I start copying multiple files.

Whenever a file is copied the value of the progress bar is reset back to 0, so when everything is copied, the only progress shown is the percentage of the last file, so if the combined total of files is 10MB, and there are 5 2MB files, the progress bar only goes up a 5th of the way.

I thought I could work around this by adding `totalBytesTransferred` to another static variable, something like this

```
public static long bytesCopied = 0;

CopyFileCallbackAction myCallback(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, object state, long totalFileSize, long totalBytesTransferred)
{
    bytesCopied += totalBytesTransferred;
    double dProgress = ((double)bytesCopied / byteCount) * 100.0;
    backupWorker.ReportProgress((int)dProgress);
    return CopyFileCallbackAction.Continue;
}
```

but I get unexpected results with this also. It seems as though the bytes being transferred is much more than the total bytes.

I can only assume it has something to do with using a new `myCallback` for each file, but now I'm really stuck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where is your progress bar declared?

Comment: It's just made in the designer.

Comment: IS your callback making a new instance each time?

Comment: Well that makes sense actually. Your updating the progress bar on each call back instead of calculating the progress over each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a flaw in an algorithm by testing it against a simple case.  Assume a file with 4 bytes and progress is reported for each byte.  So you'll get the callback 4 times with totalBytesTransferred at 1, 2, 3 and 4.  Right now you are adding them to bytesCopied so you'll add a total of 10 bytes.  For a file that's only 4 bytes.

Clearly that's wrong.  You need to wait until the CopyFileEx() is complete and *then* add the file size to bytesCopied.  That does require that you keep track of all the file sizes, which is what you wanted to avoid and got you into trouble.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that makes a lot of sense now! At what point does CopyFileEx actually finish then, so I can add the file size to bytesCopied? I can post the wrapper I am using if it would help, thanks.

Comment: It is finished when it returns.  I'm kicking in too many opened doors here.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you already said that in your answer. I managed to fix it by adding the file size for each file after every call as you suggested and it works perfectly, really appreciated it, thanks.